# Best way to drain water away from house?

Tags: drainage, french-drain

When we get rain the water flows off the cement slabs and drains into the space between the pavers. This is a small amount of water, but enough that a leak has formed in the basement. We are taking care of the crack in inside and now we want to take care of the issue outside. I am planning on doing a channel drain. I am not sure how I should drain water away from that point. Any suggestions or help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should cut back the pavers and run a buried channel drain along the edge of the concrete slab(s), away from your structure. Terminate it far from the home in an area where it won't cause harm.

[image]

Comment: I have a plan of using a channel drain to help water flow away. I can't figure out what options I have for the water to flow from the drain though. There is only small amounts of water that actually needs to be drained away from the house. It isn't like I am trying to move water coming down my downspout. I have no way I can get a drain pipe to the alley way to properly drain water away. If I can't terminate the drain above ground, do I have other options? All I could find is a dry well, which I don't think would work either.

Comment: A dry well, properly constructed and far enough away from the basement (like 30'?) should work fine with the small amount of water you are talking about. Why not?

Comment: How about just using an emitter at the end of the line? A dry well would be tough just because I have a lot of sidewalks and irrigation to go under and around to make it  to a place in the yard that I could have a dry well.

Comment: A buried "emitter", without a sump or french drain to facilitate water containment/movement, will likely cause the drain to back up. Small water maybe OK, but anything significant would then overflow the channel drain resulting in the same issue you are trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

What is the landscape like on this side of the house? In theory that little gap in the pavers should not be allowing all that much water into the ground. Does that whole side of the house slope away from the house? I would cover the area with a sheet of 5 mil sheet plastic as an experiment the next time it rains and verify that this completely reconciles the water issue. Normally semi-permeable hardscapes like pavers pitched away from the house are not high risk for water issues...

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer.